# Separar Contexto Asp.Net Identity e Contexto da aplicação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Eu estou criando um repositório utilizando o Entity Framework, e surgiu a necessidade de minhas entidades se comunicarem com 
a entidade **IdentityUser** do Identity, só que o Identity fica em uma camada separada da minha camada de aplicação.
 É possível criar dois contextos (o do Identity e o da minha aplicação) que permitam esse relacionamento de navegação entre os objetos?

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, mas não necessário, você pode usar o projeto com o Identity como referência no projeto que necessita de informações do mesmo.
Abaixo segue um video do Eduardo Pires explicando a separação do Identity:

http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2015/09/desacoplando-o-asp-net-identity-do-mvc-e-dominio/

Comment: Obrigado Anderson Roberto!